# Android titanium finish() on button

Tags: android, titanium

Ok so i want to simulate the hardware previous button by doin this on a page.

```
var buttonBack = Ti.UI.createButton({
title:"Terug",
left:10,
right:10,
top:70,
height:50
});
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(buttonBack);


buttonBack.addEventListener("click", function() {
     finish();
})
```

But i get an reference error telling me finish is not defined... Am i using this wrong? This is kinda my first titanium app so don't kill me plox :$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`finish` is a method of `Titanium.Android.Activity` so you have to get the activity first:

```
var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
activity.finish();
```

[Titanium.Android.Activity](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Android.Activity-object.html)

Comment: tyvm :) didnt find it with searching immediately o.O maybe i was doing it wrong

Comment: Thank you! I was having such a hard time figuring this out.